# Spring Boot Controller Test Failing

Tags: spring-boot, controller, mockito

I have a RestController that has just one method for http GET and is taking no input arguments. It is calling the service method which takes some arguments. Below is the controller snippet.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/leagueResults", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<LeagueTableEntry> getResults(){

    List<LeagueTableEntry> leagueTableEntryList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Match> listOfMatches = getListOfMatches();

    leagueTableEntryList = leagueService.getResults(listOfMatches);

    return leagueTableEntryList;
}
```

Below is my ControllerTest class snippet

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(LeagueController.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class LeagueControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mvc;

@MockBean
private LeagueService leagueService ;

private List<LeagueTableEntry> leagueEntryList;

private List<Match> matchList;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception 
{
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    createSampleInputData();//This method populates the instance variable matchList
    getLeagueEntryOutput();//This method populates the instance variable leagueEntryList 

}

@Test
public void checkNoOfRecordsReturned()throws Exception {
    try{
        Mockito.when(leagueService.getResults(matchList)).thenReturn(leagueEntryList);
         mvc.perform(get("/leagueResults").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                  .andExpect(status().isOk())
                  .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(4)));

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw new Exception();
    }
}

private void getLeagueEntryOutput(){
    leagueEntryList = new ArrayList<>();
    leagueEntryList.add(new LeagueTableEntry());
    leagueEntryList.add(new LeagueTableEntry());
    leagueEntryList.add(new LeagueTableEntry());
    leagueEntryList.add(new LeagueTableEntry());

}
```

So, here I am expecting the count of objects in the returned list as 4, but it is coming as 0.So, my test is failing. Can you please let me know what am i missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can instead of writing

```
Mockito.when(leagueService.getResults(matchList)).thenReturn(leagueEntryList);
```

write

```
Mockito.when(leagueService.getResults(Mockito.anyList())).thenReturn(leagueEntryList);
```

Also if this didn't work I would need to get the implementation of

```
List<Match> listOfMatches = getListOfMatches();
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked with Mockito.anyList(). Just a note, it isn't taking an argument, just 'anyList()'. Thanks again :)